# Is British thermal unit written btu or BTU?

Tags: measurements

Should I write British thermal unit as BTU or Btu?

Comment: Whatever conveys the message.  Btu and BTU are both generally accepted while btu btU bTu bTU BtU BTu are generally not accepted.

Comment: Normal units are defined in standard ISO 80000-1, so maybe there is also something similar for imperial units.